# How we add a class object in the NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

```
class1 *obj=[[class1 alloc]init];
```

I want to add this object in the NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly simple to do.

```
class1 *obj = [[class1 alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:obj];
```

Comment: Also check out the doco at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/addObject:

Comment: By the way, you forgot a bracket [ in your second line.

Comment: one more thing i want to know,I am using five button in a view, I dont want to give the location for every button then how i will place these button vertically in the view

Comment: @AnshumanMishra, that seems like a whole new question to me. In your new question please try to be as verbose as you can, include code snippets and other things you have tried. Cheers.

Comment: @AnshumanMishra Please try to find the answer on Stack Overflow and Google first though. This is a pretty common and simple issue, it's almost certainly been asked before. Stack Overflow gets enough duplicate questions as is.